# How to add more than one tab space in the body of an email in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, email, formatting, launcher

I have an email feature in my app. So i have added the \t\t so that there is a tabbed space between the first date and the value. This appears fine in the device too. But when the email is received, there is just one space between the strings and it is not tabbed. Hence the data does not appear in columns but jagged. Is there any method by which i can achieve the same look in the email received? How can i format text in `EmailComposeTask`?

```
string test = "";
strheading = "heading";
for (int j = 0; j < pCycMan.GetWeightCount(); j++)
{
    test= test+ pCycMan.GetWeightDateByIndex(j).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + "\t\t" + pCycMan.GetWeightByIndex(j) + "\n";
}
var emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask
{
    To = "emailid",
    Subject = "tezt",
};
emailComposeTask.Body = strheading + test;
emailComposeTask.Show();
```

**EDIT** :- I also tried the following code inside the for loop which did not work.

```
string temp2 =pCycMan.GetWeightByIndex(j);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(pCycMan.GetWeightDateByIndex(j).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
sb.Append("\t");
sb.Append(temp2);
sb.AppendLine();
weight = weight + sb.ToString();
```

Comment: How are you sure there is no tabs in email you received? Which tool are you using to confirm that?

Comment: The email just shows one space between the two strings..

Comment: If you are watching e-mail in a browser, for example, then all standard whitespace can be broken, since it's ignored by browsers. So, you need to look at raw e-mail data, to verify that it's really missing the tabs you've sent.

Comment: How can i find if it is inserting the space? Save the page and opening in notepad does not work. Any other method to format text?

Comment: This depends solely on email client you're using. For example in Mozilla Thunderbird you press `Ctrl+U` to view raw message data. In Gmail you click on down-arrow near reply button, and select `Show original` option.

Comment: Yea, you were right! When I clicked Show Original in Gmail and Ctrl+U in ThunderBird, the mail had tab spaces!!.

Comment: There is anyway way by which I can visually distinguish both values? Change color or something?

Answer (score 2):

If you are watching e-mail in a browser, for example, then all standard whitespace can be broken, since it's ignored by browsers. So, you need to look at raw e-mail data, to verify that it's really missing the tabs you've sent. For example in Mozilla Thunderbird you press `Ctrl+U` to view raw message data. In Gmail you click on down-arrow near reply button, and select `Show original` option.

If you want format text visually it's better to use HTML table for formatting table-like data. Specify "Content-Type: text/html" and then create html document with data (note that encodind should be specified correctly).

If you want or must use `text/plain` content type, then it's safer to use spaces to format your table data, like this, for example:

```
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Date       | Load  | Quota | Warn  | Err   |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2012-08-23 |   0.37|     5%|      0|      0|
| 2012-08-22 |   0.45|     5%|      0|      0|
| 2012-08-21 |   0.30|     5%|      0|      0|
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

But still, email client must use [Monospace font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) to read this table correctly, or the table borders and data will "flow".